# String reads Null when passing it to another Activity Android JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments, parse-platform

First of thanks for the help, and here is my problem. I am retrieving a string from an EditText and once I have the value, I am passing it on to a fragment held within another activity. Within this fragment, I obtain the string using Intent and I am using javascript to prefill a WebView. My problem is that once the string is posted onto my WebView, it reads null. I've been stuck on this for a few days now and any input would be appreciated. Thank you! Attached is part of the code where the problem should lie

```
      mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {               //was View v

            Username = mUserName.getText().toString().trim();
            Password = mPW.getText().toString().trim();
            Intent intent = new Intent(LogIn.this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("data",Password); //data is a string variable holding some value.
            startActivity(intent);



            ParseUser.logInInBackground(Username,Password, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                    if (parseUser != null & mBox.isChecked()) {

                        //If username-password & checkbox is checked;save credentials & launch
                        mUserName.setText(Username);
                        mPW.setText(Password);

                        Intent takeUserHome = new Intent(LogIn.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(takeUserHome);




                    }else if (parseUser != null) {

                        //If login matches & checkbox is not clicked, launch activity & clear
                        //username and password
                        Intent takeUserHome = new Intent(LogIn.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(takeUserHome);
                        mUserName.setText("");
                        mPW.setText("");

                    }
                    else {
                        //Clears User input from username & password if it does not match
                        mUserName.setText("");
                        mPW.setText("");
                        //Shows Alert Dialog Box
                        alert.show();


                    }
                }
            });
```

//Fragment Section

```
myWebView.loadUrl("https://accessuh.uh.edu/login.php");
    //Opens the URLs inside the WebView, not on external browser
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            String userName = currentUser.getString("username");

            String data = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
            //Names come from javascript code on webpage for each individual field
            view.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
                    "document.getElementById('parama').value = '"+userName +"';" +
                    "document.getElementById('paramb').value = '"+data+"';" +
                    "document.getElementById('login-button').click(); };");

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be

```
String data = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("data");
```

Comment: Weird seems to work half of the time now with your suggestion and crashes the fragment on the other half. Gives a java.lang.NullPointerException on this line when it does crash, any suggestions? thanks btw

Comment: that's weird. check if (data == null) after assignment of variable. If null then handle properly.